# Laravel eloquent using distinct() with wherein()?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel is it possible that we should use distinct() with wherein()?

```
$patients = Patient::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9])->get();

$groupby_patients = $patients->groupBy('gender');
```

In the `$patients` query, the distinct() is not working with `whereIn()` and I want to use distinct() in my query(), I do not want to get all-male patients and I want to select just one in the male group or just one in the female group like the example given below.

Example:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2319 ▼
    #items: array:2 [
        male,
        female
    ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to get just 1 male and 1 female, that has an `id` in `[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9]`. So if you had: `(5, male), (2, male), (5, male), (6, female), (9, female), (55, female)`, you want: `[(2, male), (9, female)]`? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct and also I want to use the same query in some where else.

Comment: Is `Id`, and `gender` the only columns you want to fetch. Or are there other columns.

Comment: No, there are other columns also.

Comment: Please share more details. What's the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 rows are considered distinct if none of the columns match in the columns selected.

For example, if we had the following patients:

| id | name | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | "John" | male |
| 5 | "John" | male |
| 10 | "Bob" | male |
| 20 | "Jamie" | male |
| 25 | "Jamie" | female |

And we did:

```php
Patient::select('name', 'gender')->distinct()->get();
```

We would get:

| name | gender |
| --- | --- |
| "John" | male |
| "Bob" | male |
| "Jamie" | male |
| "Jamie" | female |

Therefore it does not seem to be suitable for your use case.

This would be an efficient way of performing your query:

```php
$genders = ['male', 'female'];

// $genders = Patient::select('gender')->distinct(); // If you want to dynamically fetch the genders.

$patients = collect();
foreach($genders as $gender) {
    $patient = Patient::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9])->where('gender', $gender)->first();
    if ($patient !== null) {
        $patients->push($patient);
    }
}
```